# A K-space covered by finitely many open subspaces which are affine varieties is irreducible

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm following the wonderful class notes ["Introduction to algebraic geometry"][1]

In the section discussing gluing of affine varieties, there is the following exercise:

> Let $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$  be a *k*-space that can be covered by finitely many open subspaces $U_i$  that are affine varieties, such that all intersections $U_i \cap U_j$ are non-empty. Show that X is irreducible and is therefore a pre-variety

I assumed to the contrary that $X=Y\cup Z $ for some $Y,Z\subsetneq X$ closed sets. Then, for any i,
$U_i=(Y\cap U_i) \cup (Z\cap U_i)$, and that is a closed cover of an affine variety, and so, either $U_i\subset Y$ or $U_i \subset Z$, and here I got stuck.
I think that if I'll show that for any i, WLOG, $U_i\subset Y$ then it will be a contradiction, but I don't see how, and if, I could reach that coclusions.

I will appreciate any leads.

Additionally, and extra materials about the process of gluing affine varieties will be highly appreciated! I can't seem to grasp it at all.
[1]: https://www.math.ru.nl/personal/bmoonen/AlgGeom/alggeom.pdf

Comment: You have shown (something stronger than) there exists $i$ such that $U_i\subset Y$ or $U_i\subset Z$. It would be useful to know whether $U_i$ is dense.

Comment: Is it possible to know that? I know that if X is irreducible then $U_i$ will be dense as an open subset of an irreducible space. I'm not sure how to go about the other way.

Comment: How about if $V$ is any nonempty open set in $X$. There exists $j$ such that $V\cap U_j\ne\varnothing$, and $U_j$ is irreducible. Can you go from there?

Comment: Oh, I can show that the intersections of any two open subsets is non-empty, and that is eqauivalent to X being irreducible right? Without even passing through my idea.